# Parenthesis size and white space in equation with long subscripts

Tags: math-mode, spacing, brackets, subscripts, mathtools

I'm writing an equation which contains a relatively long subscritps under a summation, which is just next to a bracket. The code is the following

```
$$\mu_j=\E(X_j)=\E\left(
    \sum_{i\in Pa(X_j)}\lambda_{ij}X_i+W_j\right)
   =\sum_{i\in Pa(X_j)}\lambda_{ij}\mu_i+v_j.$$
```

With the commands `\left`, `\right` the brackets are too big and also there is too much with space between the beginning of the expression and the end of the summation. I've tried to use commands as `\mathclap`, `\mathrlap` together with `\Biggl` and similar in order to have a better looking equation, but I hadn't any satisfactory result. The problem is also that with these commands the alignment of the whole equation seems to decrease. Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: Please always post _complete_ (but small) documents (MWE). In this case your equation includes undefined commands `\E` so we can't run it, and if course the expression depends on its definition, similarly we can not see the page size you are using.

Comment: Please see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Answer (score 8):

If you swap the terms inside the brackets, the brackets are less of an obstacle:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}% Requires amssymb
\begin{document}
\[
  \mu_j=\E(X_j)=\E\bigg(
        W_j+\,\,\sum_{\mathclap{i\in Pa(X_j)}}\lambda_{ij}X_i\bigg)
       =\,\,\sum_{\mathclap{i\in Pa(X_j)}}\lambda_{ij}\mu_i+v_j.
\]
\end{document}
```

Also see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Comment: Please note that `\bigg(` and `\biggl(` are *different*: the former builds an ordinary math atom, the latter an opening atom, which is what you want here. Of course it should also be `\biggr)`.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to stack every information under the summation symbol, you can  put extra information separately. Actually I suggest to put only the index over which the summation is carried out, under the symbol. I have put three versions one below the other for comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}% Requires amssymb

\begin{document}

\[\mu_j=\E(X_j)=\E\left(
    \sum_{i\in Pa(X_j)}\lambda_{ij}X_i+W_j\right)
   =\sum_{i\in Pa(X_j)}\lambda_{ij}\mu_i+v_j\]

   Leave only the index of summation and put  more details at the end:
\[\mu_j=\E(X_j)=\E\bigg(
    \sum_{i}\lambda_{ij}X_i+W_j\bigg)
   =\sum_{i}\lambda_{ij}\mu_i+v_j, \qquad \text{where }\ i\in \underline{{Pa}}(X_{j})\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This will make the equation more readable IMHO.

Comment: I really like the last idea you propose. Thank you very much

Comment: I don't like `\forall` in that context, maybe `\text{where $i\in\mathit{Pa}(X_{j})$}`. But I'd like to underline the `\mathit{Pa}` bit, which should be used for "multiletter identifiers" such as this one.

Comment: @egreg: Pl. see the edit. Is that what you were indicating?

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't use underlining.

Comment: In your first code there's a spurious opening brace (you wrote `\{` just before `\hbox`) that appears in the lower limit of the first sum.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Well, Actually I copied it (without any hesitation) from David's answer and put it for comparison. I removed it now.

Comment: Ah, OK. I will then remove my comments shortly.

Answer (score 4):

Tricky to make it look good, perhaps

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\mu_j= E(X_j)=E\Bigl(\,\,\sum_{\hbox to 0pt{\hss$\scriptstyle i\in Pa(X_j)$\hss}}\lambda_{ij}X_i+W_j\Bigr)=
  \,\,\sum_{\hbox to 0pt{\hss$\scriptstyle i\in Pa(X_j)$\hss}}\lambda_{ij}\mu_i+v_j.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ah will fix the `\{` sorry. Yes I meant to comment that the second sum would need to match, will fix that as well.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina thanks, I think I did upload an image again, perhaps I uploaded the old one:-(